# How to fix Openlayers "Unable to load CTools exportable" errors

Tags: javascript

So, Openlayers 3.1 and 3.x Dev both have this issue. I've looked and this issue has been reported as fixed in the Drupal Openlayers issues list.

The issue is that everyone of my added layers, components, and sources each triggers these errors:

```
Unable to load CTools exportable Component (ol_users_geojson).
Unable to load CTools exportable Component (ol_geojson_chapter).
Unable to load CTools exportable Component (ol_geojson_reg_gr).
Unable to load CTools exportable Component (ol_geojson_alum).
Unable to load CTools exportable Component (google_base_layer).
Unable to load CTools exportable Component (users_popup).
```

Most of these components works in my map, except the popup, but that's a different issue. Part of the issue, is that this error is displayed prominently on my map page, even to regular users. What confuses me, is that for each of those components I'm following the OL examples, so I don't know why my custom implementations don't work. I speculate that this might have to do with the fact that the openlayers examples are all defined in code in the module, while my custom implementations are saved to the database and there might be an issue in how they are written there. There was an issue in the 2.x that some of the style component settings were getting mis-written to the db, but I haven't been able to find where in the db these are written to. From what I can tell, when I export my custom components they match those of the examples, so I'm not sure what's going on.

So, my question, which isn't obvious from the issue queue, is: is there anything I can do to fix this (patch, etc)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just got an answer from the Openlayers issues cues. The unable to load CTools errors exist when the module is looking for a missing or deleted component of a map.

In my case, I had to re-install my OL module and reconstruct the map with just the components I needed. It took some trial and error to get there.

Comment: Thanks for the info, but how to fix this?

Comment: Updated my answer with more details above. I hope this helps, this is a super annoying aspect of working with the OL module. On the other hand, I don't know of another way to be able to map multiple entities in a single map without bending over backwards with SQL trickery.

Comment: ps, did that help?

Comment: I switched to Leaflet :) Thanks for the hulp anyway!

Comment: how do you like it? I needed OL because I wanted to overlay different entity types with different numbers of field values, so complex field joins in a custom view wasn't going to work for me.